# Wait until my condition becomes true - while True python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

How can play around with **while True** in python? Here i am trying to write a python boto3 script to stop all **RDS** instances which are in available state. Before stopping, i need to change the **MultiAZ** deployed instances to none. I want to wait for the instance to get modified in-order to stop the instance. How can i accomplish the same by waiting until the condition becomes true ?

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('rds')

dbmultiAZ=[]

def lambda_handler(event,context):
 response=client.describe_db_instances()

  for i in response['DBInstances']:
    if i['DBInstanceStatus'] == 'available':
        dbmultiAZ.append(i['DBInstanceIdentifier'])


        for j in dbmultiAZ:
            if i['MultiAZ']==True:
                response1 = client.modify_db_instance(
                    DBInstanceIdentifier=i['DBInstanceIdentifier'],
                    ApplyImmediately=True,
                    MultiAZ=False
                    )

            else:
                dbmultiAZ.append(i['DBInstanceIdentifier'])


            for z in dbmultiAZ:
                waiter = client.get_waiter('db_instance_available')
                waiter.wait(
                    DBInstanceIdentifier=z )
                    response2 = client.stop_db_instance(
                        DBInstanceIdentifier=z
                        )
```

Comment: Check waiters: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html#waiters. Use the DBInstanceAvailable class to achieve what you are looking for. Your code will wait for the DB instance to become available before the next line of code is run.

Comment: `for z in dbmultiAZ:
                    waiter = client.get_waiter('db_instance_available')
                    waiter.wait(
                        DBInstanceIdentifier=z )
                    response2 = client.stop_db_instance(
                        DBInstanceIdentifier=z
                        )   `
@krishna_mee2004 will this works for me? my apologies if i am wrong. its getting error . Not waiting until the instance get modified

Comment: @EbinDavis, Why don't you update your post with the new code?

Comment: @helloV i have edited the script with _waiter_. But it wont wait for the instance to be in available state and throws error. Sorry if i am wrong Thanks